# How to upgrade Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Console without upgrade the database version itself?

Tags: oracle, flash, oracle-enterprise-manager, end-of-life

Maybe the question is not so clear.

I'm not sure about the relations of these Oracle's components.

We have an Oracle 11g with an OEM dbconsole on it.

1. Is dbconsole and databse control are actualy the same thing?
2. Since Adobe Flash EOL arrived at 31.12.2020 we want to upgrade our EM product to 13.4

Is EM database console (or database control?) depends the version of the database itself?

The only information about upgrading of OEM is for cloud control.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "EM express" (the cut down version that comes with the database), then yes, you need a later version of the DB to get the later version of EM express.

Alternatives are to use full blown OEM, but if that is not feasible, I would look at just using the DBA facilities in SQL Developer or SQL Developer Web (available via ORDS).